# how to retrieve data table in the form of table into the listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i am creating an application of extracting excel in to data table which will display in       to list ox. but problem is all the data comes row wise data into list box.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable sheet = dbConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,  null);
OleDbCommand selectCmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM   [{0}]", sheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"]), dbConn);
OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCmd);
dbAdapter.Fill(dt);


foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(row[col].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you just use the DataGridView class? Then just can set the DataTable as data source directly.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

For a listbox, you'll need to create a string representing each column. Which will be hard to align. And if you would want to modify the cell values it would be quite cumbersome.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append(row[col] + "\t");
    }
    ListBox1.Items.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```